# Exclude specific bad request from log

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging

My server has huge number of bad request from some strange path I have 20MB of log messages everyday of error:

Message = The controller for path '/dedb05bc-9359-44fe-be26-00b496aefd95/Mywebsite_files/css' was not found or does not implement IController.

The path 'Mywebsite_files/css' was never existed and the request is bad and it is created by some third party. I would like to filter this message, because it floods my log file.

What is the best way to get rid of this message in log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r using the Custom LoggingAttributeFilter in your application, then you can check for the request URL Path before writing to log.